# Irrational number in python

Tags: python

How to represent irrational numbers in Python?
e.g. I need `sqrt(2) * sqrt(2)` to be `2` (or `2.0`)

But:

```
>>> sqrt(2) * sqrt(2)   
2.0000000000000004
```

Same with floating point:

```
>>> sqrt(2.0) * sqrt(2.0)    
2.0000000000000004
```

Decimal too:

```
>>> Decimal(2).sqrt() * Decimal(2).sqrt()
Decimal('1.999999999999999999999999999')
```

Comment: Why aren't you rounding?

Comment: Nothing here is an irrational number

Comment: Because I need e.g. `sqrt(1.5) * sqrt(1.5)` to be `1.5` too

Comment: It the way it is, in any programming language, you have to round it to use.

Comment: @Ron round to the number of places from the original input or round to like the 10th place which will have a knock on effect in your examples to get the right answer.

Comment: @cricket_007 The square root of 2 is but this fact is **irr**elevant here.

Comment: Short answer: [use sympy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42149252/1600898).

Comment: @Ron do you also need `0.1+0.1+0.1` to be `0.3`? Because if you do `0.1+0.1+0.1==0.3` the result is `False`

Comment: @PhongPhung nonsense, there are plenty of symbolic languages and libraries which allow manipulation of expressions.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Both `fractions.Fraction` and `decimal.Decimal` can handle 0.1+0.1+0.1 evaluating to exactly 0.3. To do the same with irrationals you need a symbolic package.

Comment: @PeterWood: please en-light me, I'm new

Comment: @PhongPhung e.g. [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html). The tutorial [has an example](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/intro.html#what-is-symbolic-computation) using `sqrt(8)`.

Comment: @PeterWood: great, thanks